# f2matlab error while coverting fortran to matlab

Tags: matlab, fortran

I have been trying to convert a fortran code into matlab using `f2matlab`, but I have been running into some serious errors.

After calling the `f2matlab` file using the full file name, I get the error while converting:

> Error in funwords=getfunwordsonly;
>   . Undefined function or variable 'getfunwordsonly'.

I am not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

getfunwordsonly.m is an m-file that should be in the directory where you unzipped f2matlab. Check for that and perhaps reinstall if you don't have it.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I checked for the m-file and I do have it. But I still encounter the same problem. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @user2581835 Is the file in a location which is part of your Matlab search path?